# Python twisted client server interface

Tags: python, django, client-server, twisted

I'm designing a domotic network, which would basically consist in a main node that will act as a front-end where a web server will be hosted and a bunch of client nodes such as video entry-phone, irrigation control, alarm ...

The client nodes would register themselves on the front-end which would be, at that point, able of controlling their functionalities. I would like to use python for this project, so twisted and django would be the two main frameworks.

What's the smoothest way of having the clients interfaced with the front-end ?

The clients themselves could serve a webpage but I'm not really happy with this solution since I would like to have a single, main web server.

Could a light web server (twisted web server for instance) lazily turned on by the frontend if the user wants to control a given client be a solution here ?

What about defining some "public" amp.Command classes which could be adapted by the server to paint the client's specific web interface ? (some client business would need to be on server side that way)

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: This question is way too broad.  Please make it more specific, ideally with code samples.  It's actually about 20 different questions :).

Comment: I know, its more like an high level design question rather than a specific code question, I didn't know if this was the right place to ask it but I've seen other design oriented questions so I have tried it out..

Comment: It's like 9 different high level design questions, and not enough to answer any of them :).

Comment: The Twisted mailing list might be a more appropriate place to have this discussion, since it's not really a question.